# Cell values getting truncated while excel upload

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2007, excel-interop

I am using following code for excel upload

```
 OleDbConnection sSourceConnection;
            string properties = "Excel 8.0; HDR=NO; IMEX=1;";//properties set for connection to excel
            string sSourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"" + properties + "\"";
            sSourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(sSourceConstr);//creating the OLEDB connection
            try
            {
                //select statement to select data from the first excel sheet
                string sql = string.Format("Select * FROM [{0}]", "Sheet1$");

                //commands to fill the dataset with excel data
                OleDbDataAdapter excelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, sSourceConnection);
                sSourceConnection.Open();
                excelAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                excelAdapter.Fill(dSet, EXCEL_DATA);
```

I have to upload around 300 records. One column has some text comments. The length of comments varies from 10 chars to 1000 chars. But all of comments above 255 length are getting truncated in that column.

I have used this post [Excel cell-values are truncated by OLEDB-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898513/excel-cell-values-are-truncated-by-oledb-provider) to change a registry setting, but it didn't work.

I have also tried everything mentioned in the post [OleDB & mixed Excel datatypes : missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data/5721521#5721521), still nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ACE engine so the correct place to update the registery is

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRowsHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows`

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft Office 2010-2013-2016/365

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel
```

And better is to scan for the text ‘TypeGuessRows’ and when you find it, in combination with Excel, set its value to 0. We’ve found another important location for this behavior at this location

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office \ClickToRun\REGISTRY \MACHINE\Software \Wow6432Node \Microsoft \Office\16.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel.
```