# sqlbulkcopy reads only 255 characters

Tags: c#

I am using sqlbulkcopy class to read excel in a table

```
 string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + targetFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
    //OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + targetFileName + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;HDR=YES;""");
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", con);


    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CrossMediaConnectionString"].ToString()))
        try
        {
            {
                #region SqlBulkCopy
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_TempProductData";

                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("product_code", "ProductCode");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("product_name", "ProductName");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("category_relation_id", "RelatedCategoryId");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("short_description", "ProductDescription");



       con.Open();

               bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myCommand.ExecuteReader());

    }
}
```

but ProductDescription reads only 255 characters even for table tbl_TempProductData I have set length to max

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel cell-values are truncated by OLEDB-provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898513/excel-cell-values-are-truncated-by-oledb-provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [rmoore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90435/rmoore) said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898513/excel-cell-values-are-truncated-by-oledb-provider),

The OLEDB provider for excel will attempt to automatically determine the DataTypes based off of the first 8 rows of data, this can be set with the HDR=Yes/No property in the connection string. Additionally, there are multiple types that it can apply to text columns. The memo type holds over 255 characters, so if none of the first 8 rows have that then it will incorrectly set the data type.

The way to change this is by changing a registry setting called TypeGuessRows, as described here:[Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517)

NOTE: The valid range of values for the TypeGuessRows key is 0 to 16. However, if the value is 0, the number of source rows scanned is 16384. So if you have a very large file make sure the biggest rows are first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my connection string.
 I think the extended property may help you..

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"", fileName);
```