# LinqToExcel returning blank rows for .csv files

Tags: c#, csv, linq-to-excel

I've been using LinqToExcel to import data from .xlsx files successfully for a while. Recently, however, I was sent a .csv file that I'm unable to read the data of.

Let's say that the file contains the following data:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
 A    B    C
 D    E    F
```

I've created a class for mapping the columns as such:

```
public class Test
{
    [ExcelColumn("Col1")]
    public string Col1 { get; set; }

    [ExcelColumn("Col2")]
    public string Col2 { get; set; }

    [ExcelColumn("Col3")] 
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I try to read the data like so:

```
var test = from c in excel.Worksheet<Test>()
           select c;
```

The query successfully returns two Test-objects, but all property values are null.

I even tried to read the data without class and header:

```
var test = from c in excel.WorksheetNoHeader()
select c;
```

In this case, the query also returns two rows, both with three cells/values. But again all of these values are null. What could be the issue here?

I should also note that the file opens and looks perfectly fine in Excel. Furthermore using StreamReader, I'm able to read all of its rows and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of data is in each of those columns? (string, numeric, ...)

According to [Initializing the Microsoft Excel driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/initializing-the-microsoft-excel-driver?tabs=office-2016)

**TypeGuessRows**

> The number of rows to be checked for the data type. The data type is
> determined given the maximum number of kinds of data found. If there
> is a tie, the data type is determined in the following order: Number,
> Currency, Date, Text, Boolean. If data is encountered that does not
> match the data type guessed for the column, it is returned as a Null
> value. On import, if a column has mixed data types, the entire column
> will be cast according to the ImportMixedTypes setting. The default
> number of rows to be checked is 8. Values are of type REG_DWORD.

See post [Can I specify the data type for a column rather than letting linq-to-excel decide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739269/can-i-specify-the-data-type-for-a-column-rather-than-letting-linq-to-excel-decid)

The post [Setting TypeGuessRows for excel ACE Driver](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/41222f92-b079-4e6c-ae17-3aa3534a45a7/setting-typeguessrows-for-excel-ace-driver) states how to change the value for TypeGuessRows.

> When the driver determines that an Excel column contains text data,
> the driver selects the data type (string or memo) based on the longest
> value that it samples. If the driver does not discover any values
> longer than 255 characters in the rows that it samples, it treats the
> column as a 255-character string column instead of a memo column.
> Therefore, values longer than 255 characters may be truncated. To
> import data from a memo column without truncation, you must make sure
> that the memo column in at least one of the sampled rows contains a
> value longer than 255 characters, or you must increase the number of
> rows sampled by the driver to include such a row. You can increase the
> number of rows sampled by increasing the value of TypeGuessRows under
> the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
> registry key.
>
> One more thing we need to keep in mind is that the registry
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows
> only applies to Excel 97- 2003. For Excel 2007 and higher version,
> Excel Open XML (.XLSX extension) actually uses ACE OLE DB provider
> rather JET provider. If you want to keep the file extension as .XLSX,
> you need to modify the following registry key according to your Excel
> version:
>
> Excel 2007: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access
> Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows Excel 2010:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity
> Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows Excel 2013:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access Connectivity
> Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows

Comment: This seems to be my exact issue. All cells have the "General"-format, but most of the columns contain text rather than numbers. I tried opening the file and setting the format to "Text" and then LinqToExcel was able to read the data! Normally, however, I can't open the file and change this manually. Nor can I make changes to the registry. So how do i get around this issue?

Comment: Have you considered using Nuget package `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`?

Comment: I ended up using the Nuget package CsvReader to handle my .csv files instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to materialize your query by calling `ToList` or `ToArray` at the end?

I tried to recreate your case and had no trouble reading the data from the Excel file using the following code snippet:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(FilePath);
List<Test> tests = (
    from c in excel.Worksheet<Test>()
    select c
)
.ToList();
```

It returns two objects with all properties filled properly.

One minor thing, when I added `ToList` initially, I got the following exception:

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'
```

Which according to what they say in [the official docs](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel#access-database-engine) seems reasonable since I was missing [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Distributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255) on my machine.

Comment: Yeah, It's the same issue with ToList(). And I have Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Distributable on my machine (no errors).