# orA-01843: not a valid month while uploading excel in bulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, datetime

I have an `Excel Upload` in which there are columns for dates which while uploading is giving me error as

> orA-01843: not a valid month while uploading excel in bulkCopy

Below is the code.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Coneection String by default empty
        string ConStr = "";
        //Extantion of the file upload control saving into ext because 
        //there are two types of extation .xls and .xlsx of excel 
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadIPFee.FileName).ToLower();
        //getting the path of the file 
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/UploadData/" + FileUploadIPFee.FileName);
        //saving the file inside the MyFolder of the server
        FileUploadIPFee.SaveAs(path);
        
        if (ext.Trim() == ".xls")
        {
            //connection string for that file which extantion is .xls
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        else if (ext.Trim() == ".xlsx")
        {
            //connection string for that file which extantion is .xlsx
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        //making query
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
        //Providing connection
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
        //checking that connection state is closed or not if closed the 
        //open the connection
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        //create command object
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        // create a data adapter and get the data into dataadapter
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //fill the excel data to data set
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SaveUsingOracleBulkCopy("IPCOLO_IPFEE_CALC_MST", dt);
        }
        conn.Close();

      //  SaveUsingOracleBulkCopy("IPCOLO_IPFEE_CALC_MST", dtExcelRows);
    }

    public void SaveUsingOracleBulkCopy(string destTableName, DataTable dt)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString_IPCOLO"].ToString();
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var bulkCopy = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy(connection, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destTableName;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);  // here is the error

                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Data Uploaded Successfully')", true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Knowing close to nothing about asp.net I can only say that in general using `SELECT *` is a recepy for desaster. May be you should list the columns explicitely and convert the `DATE` columns in the expected format. But I'm not sure how this could case `ORA-01834`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: ok, will do that... but can you provide one sample column with value example for me to understand it ?

Comment: What are the data types for each column in the Excel file? OLEDB tries to guess the data types by looking at a few rows of data. See "TypeGuessRows" in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/initializing-the-microsoft-excel-driver?tabs=office-2016. Here are some other useful posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739269/can-i-specify-the-data-type-for-a-column-rather-than-letting-linq-to-excel-decid, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238505/linqtoexcel-returning-blank-rows-for-csv-files/65240185#comment115419048_65240185

Comment: Adding columns to a DataTable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-columns-to-a-datatable

Comment: @user9938: datatypes are different, for ex: for date column i have set format as `Date` in excel. for normal string it is set as `Text`

Comment: Are there any null values for "Date"? You may want to consider using NuGet package `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`. See "Parse and read a large spreadsheet document (Open XML SDK):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet

Comment: No, there are no null values.. if you want I can share my excel data in an image and show you

Comment: Providing some sample data may be helpful

Comment: Also see this article "Using bulk inserts on databases"  https://ewinnington.github.io/posts/bulk-inserts

Comment: you have checked that the date format in the excel fit the DB date format?