Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ignores data in a column
I use this code to load .xlsx to my C# software.
Connection = new OleDbConnection(
@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
@"Data Source='" + FileWork + "';" +
@"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR = YES""");

Connection.Open();

var dtSchema = Connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
OriginTableName = "[" + dtSchema.Rows[0].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME") + "]"; // first sheet

Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + OriginTableName, Connection);
MyData.Clear();
Adapter.Fill(MyData);

I discovered that it completely ignores any data in a column when several first rows of the column are empty. Then nothing from the column is loaded. Once there is at least a space in one of the first rows of the column, it loads correctly all.
My xlsx looks like this (ULICE is a header):

Any idea what to do? I already tried "TypeGuessRows=0" "ImportMixedTypes=Text" "IMEX=1" in my connection string, that doesn't help.

I have just tried a similar test and it seems that the driver always ignores the first row in the table. This requires further investigation.

These drivers expect a Schema.ini file to set out the format.  If it doesn't exist, they fall back to inferring everything about the schema from a sample of the first few rows - not only the number of columns, but also data types etc.  It can lead to all sorts of irritating problems.  See: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/OLE-DB/provider/Microsoft-Access-database-engine/engines/Text/schema_ini/index

Just noticed it's an xlsx - I long gave up on the Oledb drivers for that in .NET - there's libraries which provide a much easier way to work with it.  I've had good expereinces with NPOI in the past, but there's quiet a few out there.

@Ian The schema.ini file is only for text and csv files, The excel schema is in the file itself, and located as shown in the questioner's code. I now go for t he Excel Interop, but keep my OleDB code for reference.

I have just tried some further testing and setting HDR=NO in the extended properties now gives me the first line of the table. Most confusing.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238505/linqtoexcel-returning-blank-rows-for-csv-files/65240185#65240185
