# How can we update a cell in excel with string which is more than 256 characters length using oledb

Tags: excel, oledb, oledbcommand, oledbexception

I'm trying to update a cell in excel using Oledb, but the data which I'm trying to add to excel is more than 256 characters length. So, when I execute the update query, it is throwing error like,
**The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data.**

How can we update excel cell with String which has more than 256 characters?

Comment: You can get help in this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898513/excel-cell-values-are-truncated-by-oledb-provider

Comment: I tried the solutions in that, but no luck.
When I set IMEX=1 and executed the update query, it is throwing error like "Execute Non Query for Failed Records: Operation must use an updateable query."